# replace X in mysql query with data from a button press

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Im trying to create a webpage that outputs a table where if you press a button on the webpage and that value is present in the database it shows all items with the value.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `alergen` (
  `Product` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `Gluten` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `Nuts` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `Diary` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `Shellfish` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `Egg` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `alergen` (`Product`, `Gluten`, `Nuts`, `Diary`, `Shellfish`, `Egg`) VALUES
  ('White Toast', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No'),
  ('Danish Pastry', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'),
  ('Full English', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'),
  ('Fruit Scone', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a798ff6/1

where in the query egg would be the variable

so my query would look like

```
select product from table where X = "Yes";
```

and x would be the value of the button
with the buttons being.

```
<input type="submit" name="Gluten" class="button" value="Gluten" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Milk" class="button" value="Milk" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Egg" class="button" value="Egg" /> 
<input type="submit" name="ShellFish" class="button" value="Shellfish" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Nuts" class="button" value="Nuts" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately you have the database design wrong. Imagine if people come up with another 10 things they are interested in, or maybe another 100. Your design would not cope well with that. You need to move the subjects (Guten, Milk, etc etc ) into a seperate table

Comment: @RiggsFolly how is it that the table design is wrong? if the allergens are in a seperate table how would i link the allergy to the food?

Comment: A link table between the 2. I suggest a look at a Database Design tutorial, there are hundereds on the internet

Comment: Suggestion: Product table, Alergen table and ProductHasAlergen table The link table ProductHasAlergen will contain just 2 columns `product_id` and a `alergen_id` signifying that the Product with that id has the Alergen with alergen_id in it. That way a product can be linked to ONE or THOUSANDS of alergens

Comment: That also means that the column names in your queries would always be know in advance and the parameters would for the data instead

Comment: You can also get a little more clever and add other fields to the link table, in this case maybe a quantity column indicating that there is 2 grams of Gluten in this specific product... for example

Comment: Incidentally, there's no such thing as a 'gluten allergy'